# Java string join to string

Tags: java, foreach

Assume i have List Collection of Strings and i want to loop by this List and add each element of List to some variable of type String.

```
List<String> words;
//assume words have 5 elements
String summary;//variable where i want to keep all elements

for (String word : words){
    //here i want to add new word to the variable summary
}
```

As i know java always creates new object of String. Even if i try to change value - new object will be created anyway, am i right?

So here is a question how to join all elements of List in one variable?

Comment: you can use StringBuilder

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Answer (score 3):

On any version of Java:
[Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) has a class StringUtils that has a join method:

```
String result = StringUtils.join(words, ",")
```

On Java 8, you can do this natively. See [this article.](http://www.mscharhag.com/2014/03/java-8-string-joining.html)

Answer (score 1):

use a StringBuilder to join all the words.

```
List<String> words;
//assume words have 5 elements
StringBuilder summary = new StringBuilder();

for (String word : words){
    summary.append(word);
}
```

Finally, get the joined String with `summary.toString()`.

Note : If you have an idea of the number of characters that would be appended to the StringBuilder, it will be more efficient to use the constructor that gets an initial size :

`summary = new StringBuilder(size);`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution would be to use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
String summary;
List<String> words = ...;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String word : words) {
    builder.append(word);
}

summary = builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use an existing functionality, for example Apache Common's [`StringUtils.join()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.String)). If that's not possible, this will work:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : words) {
        sb.append(word);
    }
    String summary = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code,

```
List<String> words;
String summary = null;

for (String word : words)
{
    summary = summary + word + " , ";
}
System.out.println("List items : " + summary);
```

Comment: Inefficient due to repeated creations of a String object.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Apache commons (StringUtils) is Guava's Joiner.

For example:

```
 List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
 words.add("word");
 words.add("anotherWord");

 String joinedWords = Joiner.on(",").join(words);
```

This may also be useful if you're not able to use Java 8.

See wiki:
https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained

Answer (score 0):

As Eran suggest or just, use simple concatination

```
List<String> words;
//assume words have 5 elements
String summary = "";//variable where i want to keep all elements

for (String word : words){
    summary = summary + word;
}
```

Comment: This is terribly inefficient, it'll create intermediate strings and will end up being `O(n^2)` (see: [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm)). Use a `StringBuilder` instead, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at

```
StringUtils.join()
```

as a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
String summary = words.stream().collect( Collectors.joining() );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add.

```
summary += word;
```

Comment: summary is initially null: you can't do that.